# Mapping domain objects to result sets instead of tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on an application that uses an existing database which is accessed exclusively through Stored Procs.  Most of these SPs return columns from multiple tables.

We have a Data Access Layer that returns objects of types from our Domain Object Layer.  However, since the SPs return columns from multiple tables, I'm unsure how I should structure my domain objects since most of them don't "naturally" map to the data returned from the SPs.

Example:
Stored Proc returns columns from "Employee" table and "Manager" table:
-EmployeeId
-FirstName
-LastName
-ManagerEmployeeId
-ManagerFirstName
-ManagerLastName

Should I create a domain object "EmployeeWithManager" that contained properties which exactly match the columns above?

Should I create some sort of "Data Access Object" which contains an Employee object and a Manager object?

Unfortunately, using an ORM, parameterized queries, or changing the Stored Procs is not an option.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by using an ORM, parameterized queries is not an option?  I would only create Manager and Employee Objects only as the domain objects should be matched to the domain.  If you want to get employee, you call the SP and only use the employee portion of the result, if you want manager, you call the SP and only use the manager portion of the result.

Comment: @john I mean that the company that I'm working doesn't want to use an ORM or parameterized queries, and I'm not in a position to make this change.  I must access the DB through the existing SPs.  I realize the domain objects should match the domain.  I like your approach, but if I need both the employee and the manager in a particular part of my program, I'd have to call the same SP twice with the same parameters.  I'd prefer to get the entire result and then map it to my domain objects to avoid two round-trips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand.  This is what I would do, still create the domain objects that matches matches your domain.

Reason being

1. Easier to understand
2. assuming you create EmployeeWithManager with one SP, if you have another SP (say Employee with Car), you would need to create EmployeeWithCar object, the list goes on, won't be manageable and you will have a lot of work trying to convert between them

My approach,

- Create two domain objects, Employee and Manager (your Manager can
  even inherit Employee)
- In Employee, create a reference/relation to Manager, e.g.

> ```
> Class Employee{
>
>     String Id;
>     String FirstName;
>     ...
>
>     Manager EmployeeManager;
>
> }
> ```

- Create your data access layer to use your SP, e.g.

> ```
>  Class EmployeeDAL{
>
>         Employee GetEmployeeWithManager(string EmployeeId){
>             //user data reader to populate your Employee object and fill it with Manager
>             Manager m = New Manager(); //fill Manager from SP
>             Employee e = New Employee(); //fill Employee from SP
>
>             e.EmployeeManager = m;
>             return e;
>         }
>     }
> ```

- In your business logic/UI,

> ```
> Class EmployeeController{
>      PopulateEmployee(string EmployeeId){
>           Employee e = EmployeeDAL.GetEmployeeWithManager(EmployeeId);
>           Databind(e);
>           'you can also access your manager from e.EmployeeManager
>      }
> ```
>
> }